# How do I represent a graph given as an adjacency list in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures, graph

I am going to program various graph algorithms, and as input, I have given graphs on the form of adjacency lists.

Here's an example:

1 2 3 4

2 1 3 4

3 1 2 4

4 1 2 3 5

5 4 6

6 5

The graph has 6 vertices, represented by 6 rows (and the first entry of each row denotes the number of the vertex representing that row). The remaining entries in a row denote the vertices that the vertex corresponding to that row are adjacent to.

What is a good way of representing this in C#? The differing number of entries in each row seem to rule out an array, so I found these [lists of lists](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nested-list).

I am going to manipulate the graph, e.g. [contract edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction), and I am looking for a data structure in which graph manipulations are both possible and efficient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73504595/4393351

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like dictionary with a list of integers as a value structure cold be useful:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> graph = new Dictionary <int, List<int>>();
        graph[1] = new List<int> {2, 3, 4};
        graph[2] = new List<int> {1, 3, 4};
        graph[3] = new List<int> {1, 2, 4};
        graph[4] = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 5};
        graph[5] = new List<int> {4, 6};
        graph[6] = new List<int> {5};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When I had a similar task, I found it easy to have the following classes:

```
    class Edge
    {
    public Node From;
    public Node To;
    }

    class Node
    {
         public List<Edge> EdgesIn;
         public List<Edge> EdgesOut;
    }

    class Graph
    {
         public List<Node> Nodes;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean I create an object Node and an object Edge for each node and edge in my graph? I wonder if I have a large graph, say the Facebook graph with users as nodes, and edges as users being friends, will it be hard performancewise to keep track of that many objects?

Answer (score 1):

If you'll choose coding of custom classes for working with graphs
[this info](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/40graphs/) may be helpful. But all info here on `java`

Answer (score 1):

I found that a convenient way of representing graphs is the GraphSON format. You can check it out here: [GraphSON format](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphSON-Reader-and-Writer-Library). An example of it:

```
{
   "graph": {
       "mode":"NORMAL",
       "vertices": [
           {
               "_id": "1",
               "_type": "vertex"
           },
           {
               "_id": "2",
               "_type": "vertex"
           },
           {
               "_id": "3",
               "_type": "vertex"
           }
       ],
       "edges": [
           {
               "weight": 1,
               "_id": "11",
               "_type": "edge",
               "_outV": "2",
               "_inV": "1"
           },
           {
               "weight": 0.5,
               "_id": "12",
               "_type": "edge",
               "_outV": "3",
               "_inV": "2"
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjacency List working example in C#. Converting the Edges to the Adjacency List in C#

```
            int[][] edges = new int[][]
            {
                new int[] { 0, 1 },
                new int[] { 1, 2 },
                new int[] { 2, 0 }
            };

            var graph = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < edges.Length; i++)
            {
                var pair = edges[i];

                if (!graph.ContainsKey(pair[0])) graph.Add(pair[0], new List<int>());
                if (!graph.ContainsKey(pair[1])) graph.Add(pair[1], new List<int>());

                graph[pair[0]].Add(pair[1]);
                graph[pair[1]].Add(pair[0]);
            }
```